# Как получить количество записей MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Допустим у меня такая структура :

```
{name : 'John', group : [one, two]}
{name : 'Dony', group : [one, three]}
```

И мне нужно вывести: *one - 2 , two - 1, three - 1*

Как это реализовать в MongoDB ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это делается с помощью [MapReduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce),
смотрите второй пример

Для вашей коллекции это будет выглядеть

функция map

```
> m = function() { 
... this.group.forEach(
... function(name){
...             emit( name , { count : 1 } );
...         }
...     );
... };
```

функция  reduce

```
> r = function( key , values ){
...     var total = 0;
...     for ( var i=0; i<values.length; i++ )
...         total += values[i].count;
...     return { count : total };
... };
```

Запускаем MapReduce

```
db.test.mapReduce(m, r, { out : "myoutput" } );
```

и в коллекцию "myoutput " сохраняется результат

```
> db.myoutput.find()
{ "_id" : "one", "value" : { "count" : 2 } }
{ "_id" : "three", "value" : { "count" : 1 } }
{ "_id" : "two", "value" : { "count" : 1 } }
```

Comment: Инфа для новичков - старайтесь избегать активного использования MapReduce, если так важен именно такой формат и 100% точность данных не важна - лучше делать агрегацию где-то на слейве по определенному интервалу.

Answer (score 0):

Не силен в MongoDB, но к примеру в ElasticSearch для этого есть фасеточный запрос данных (Facets). Довольно просто и удобно выдает как раз такую статистическую информацию. Google по запросу "Facets MongoDB" тоже что-то выдает